# 'This' undefined when calling class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to set a response message to the user, but when I do I get an error. (Cannot read property 'message' of undefined) This is the code that doesn't work:

server.js

```
const server = express();
let  App =  require('./controllers/app');
App = new App();
server.use('/', App.router);

http.createServer(server).listen(8080);
```

app.js

```
class App {
    constructor () {
        this.message = '';
    } 

    router (request, response) {
        if (request.url === '/register') {
            response.render('register.ejs', {
                url: request.url,
                header: headBase + 'register',
                message: this.message, //  This is where the error is triggered
                user: username
            });
            this.message = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Anywhere i try to set or read `this.message` in the router method i get the error.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/497418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
let  App =  require('./controllers/app');
App = new App();
server.use('/', App.router);
```

Before I dive into the real issue, I'll also mention that overriding `App` with an *instance* of App is a bad idea, so I'm going to rewrite this as:

```
const App = require('./controllser/app')
const app = new App();
server.use('/', app.router);
```

Now it's more clear that what you're passing in is the method reference from the instance of `App`.

The problem is that you're passing the function, but the function is not bound to `app` in any way. There are a variety of ways you can fix this.

The simplest is to pass `app.router.bind(app)` which wraps `app.router` in a function that calls `app.router` in the context of `app`:

```
server.use('/', app.router.bind(app))
```

The next simplest (as you're using ES2015 features) is to wrap the function in a lambda:

```
server.use('/', (...args) => app.router(...args))
```

Comment: I thought a fixed it myself by saying 'App.message', but this is much better solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around it. I just changed `this.message` to `App.message` in the router method.

```
class App {
    constructor () {
        this.message = '';
    } 

    router (request, response) {
        if (request.url === '/register') {
            response.render('register.ejs', {
                url: request.url,
                header: headBase + 'register',
                message: App.message,
                user: username
            });
            App.message = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to zzzzBov solution can be to bind the method in the constructor:

```
class App {
    constructor () {
        this.message = '';
        this.router = this.router.bind(this)
    } 

    router (request, response) {
        if (request.url === '/register') {
            response.render('register.ejs', {
                url: request.url,
                header: headBase + 'register',
                message: this.message,
                user: username
            });
            this.message = '';
        }
    }
}
```